# Package a list of packages is it possible?

Tags: lightning, package, unmanaged-package

Hi so apparently I have made some progress on the org and packaged the features . Assuming that I have features : foo and bar.
and packages : foo-package and bar-package

can i package both of them to one?
foo-bar-package that contains both foo and bar? or should i do a manual uploading of files that are inside foo and inside of bar  or is there an easier way? apparently I am uploading like 200+ files and human error percentage is really high .

FYI

In my scenario I need to package 12 features. That is already packaged individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packaging 1.0 (aka Classic Packages) does not particularly support nested packages. However, you could always use DX to retrieve both packages, then create a third package that contains the contents of both. It's also possible create unlocked packages that would behave in a similar manner, except that dependencies have to be installed anyways, so you'd really just end up having three packages to install instead of two, with no benefit. That said, it sounds like you could benefit from Unlocked Packages in order to keep those features separately installable and upgradeable.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. What a great help you are to the community. Cheers!